# ButterKnife setup issues using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm using `SherlockActivity` (I know not to use it, but I need it for this project) and i'm trying to get ButterKnife to work with it. For some reason, I keep getting a series of errors and i'm not sure why, as I'm following the documentation. My code is as per below:

```
public class ViewMessageActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.id_message_list)
    ListView listView;

    @OnItemClick(R.id.id_message_list)
    void onItemClick(int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.message_details);
        ButterKnife.setDebug(true);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
```

The errors i'm getting are below:

```
ButterKnife﹕ Looking up view injector for com.app.ViewMessageActivity
ButterKnife﹕ Not found. Trying superclass com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
ButterKnife﹕ Not found. Trying superclass android.app.Activity
ButterKnife﹕ MISS: Reached framework class. Abandoning search.
```

Is there any reason for this? I followed documentation on this page:

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

and the sample:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-sample/src/main/java/com/example/butterknife/SimpleActivity.java

Comment: How are you building this project? Looks like the code generation isn't running.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason my settings in Android Studio were reverted, not sure how. But make sure annotation processing is enabled in Android Studio.

Screenshot explains it all.

[image]